# Google Map Fragment in a Circular View

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to display a Google Map fragment inside a circular view. This is the XML layout I have defined:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="200dp">



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_height="200dp"
         />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


</FrameLayout>
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]

As you can see the map fragment is covering the whole frame layout thereby making it rectangle. I want to bound it inside the circle.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it's working.

Comment: Sorry it's not working

Comment: The edited answer is tried and tested. Will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a framelayout as a container to your fragment and add a background to the framelayout

framelayout container

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_background"></FrameLayout>
```

circular_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#B1BCBE" />
<corners android:radius="200dip" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dip"
    android:left="0dip"
    android:right="0dip"
    android:top="0dip" />
```

add the fragment dynamically to your application

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new Circular_fragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Using a support map fragment doesn't work. It still shows up a square view

Comment: Just added the support map fragment tag inside the FrameLayout.

Comment: Try adding it dynamically using FragmentManager.

Comment: Sorry it's doesn't work that way too. The map loads as a square only